# Review of my CSS for aligning the navigation icons and text in a footer menu

Tags: html, css

The navigation in my footer menu looks like this

[image: footer navigation]

It works, but I get a feeling that using spans the way I did was a bit of a hack. So I would also like to know how to maximize compatibility as used media queries.

I created it using the following

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
    <ul>

      <li><a href="http://www.bruxzir.com">
        <span>HOME</span><span>&raquo;</span>
      </a></li>

      <li><a href="http://www.bruxzir.com/features-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/">
        <span>FEATURES</span><span>&raquo;</span>
      </a></li>

      <li><a href="http://www.bruxzir.com/video-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/index.aspx">
        <span>VIDEOS</span><span>&raquo;</span>
      </a></li>

      <li><a href="http://www.bruxzir.com/cases-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/">
        <span>CASES</span><span>&raquo;</span>
      </a></li>

      <li><a href="http://www.bruxzir.com/testimonials-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/">
        <span>TESTIMONIALS</span><span>&raquo;</span>
      </a></li>

      <li><a href="/">
        <span>BLOG</span><span>&raquo;</span>
      </a></li>

      <li><a href="http://www.bruxzir.com/authorized-bruxzir-labs-zirconia-dental-crown/">
        <span>AUTHORIZED BRUXZIR LABS</span><span>&raquo;</span>
      </a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
  background-color: #111; 
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 120px;
  padding: 24px 0; 
}

.footer a { 
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none; 
}

.footer ul { list-style: none; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 479px) { 
  .footer { text-align: left; }
  .footer ul li { 
    display: block; 
    padding: 12px; 
  }
  .footer ul li a { } 
  .footer ul li a span:nth-of-type(2) {
    padding:9px;
    background-color: rgb(202, 0,0 );
    float: right;
    border-radius:2px;
  }
}  

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) { 
  .footer { text-align: center; }
  .footer ul li { display: inline; }
  .footer ul li:not(:last-of-type) { margin-right: 12px }
  .footer ul li a span:nth-of-type(2) { display: none; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use a `<div>` where you need to separate a block of code from the rest, for positioning or for other purposes, your use of the `div` for the Footer section is correct, so that you can place this part of the page at the bottom, where it belongs.

when you create a list item (`<li>`) it is already a text element.  you can perform CSS on these elements the same as you would a `<p>` Paragraph tag  if you add a `<p>` tag inside the list item it may give you unwanted results like a `carriage return` after the element.

I think that using the `<span>` tag the way you did is just fine.  I would have probably added a class to each of them, it would have been easier to pick them out with the CSS. other than that your `<span>` tags were used properly in this instance because they were used **inline**

Answer (score 6):

**HTML:**

- Since the the navigation is the only thing inside your `<div class="footer">`, how about moving the class to the `ul`?
- Instead of using `span`'s there, you can add the `&raquo;` to a pseudo-element (see the CSS part)

**CSS:**

- For your arrows, you should use pseudo-elements:

  ```
  .footer a:after {
      content: "\00BB";
      float: right;
      padding: 9px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      background-color: #ca0000; /* hex-based values are shorter */
  }
  ```

  You won't need to hide them on bigger screens either, if you define them inside a media query, because they're not present in your markup
- Instead of actually writing the links in capital letters, write them like you would in normal language and make them appear uppercase with `text-transform: uppercase;`
- I don't see a purpose for the `min-width: 1px` part in your media query. Just unnecessary.
- Defining `display: block;` on list-items is not necessary, because they behave like block-level elements already
- Select `.footer li` instead of `.footer ul li` and `.footer a` instead of `.footer ul li a`. No need for this extra layer of specificity and dependency. There will probably no other links and list-items in this ul other than these you already have